# escape single quotes in perl

Tags: mysql, perl, escaping

I have the following code:

```
my $body = $in{'article'};
```

Here is my database insertion code:

```
my $stmt = $db->prepare("insert into news_articles (createdate, userid, status, title, inline, content, attribution, pending) values(unix_timestamp(), $user->{'uid'}, 0, '$title', '$pullquote', '$body', '$attr', 0)");
```

It seems to fail when i have a single quote inside the `$body` variable.

I've tried escaping it using:

```
$body = $db->quote($body);
```

And also:

```
$body = qq($body);
```

I'm very new to Perl, but how can I safely escape single quotes prior to the insertion?

Comment: [Placeholders](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values) are almost always the way to go, but `quote` should work. Can you please create a [mcve] that shows how the value of `$body` is set and any errors you get?

Answer (score 4):

`$body = $db->quote($body)` is the correct way to do this, but note that the `quote` method also adds the outer quotation marks, so you would use just `$body` in your SQL statement instead of `'$body'`

However, using `prepare` together with placeholders is by far the best method all-round. It supplies the necessary quoting for you, and also allows a prepared statement to be reused several times with different `execute` parameters

I find *here documents* useful for writing SQL statements with some layout so that they are readable. Your code would look like this

```
my $body = $in{article};

my $stmt = $db->prepare(<<END_SQL);
INSERT INTO news_articles (createdate, userid, status, title, inline, content, attribution, pending)
VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
END_SQL

$stmt->execute($user->{'uid'}, 0, $title, $pullquote, $body, $attr, 0);
```